# submit based on the Javascript function called via onclick attribute in <h:commandbutton>

Tags: javascript, jsf

In a form i used  i called a Javascript function. Though the function returns false , form is submitted and action method is called.

i used like this

```
<h:commandButton onclick="test();" action="{#bean.menthod}">
```

test- javascript method returns boolean value false.

Above doesnt work. Below mentioned code alone worked. I want to know why

```
 <h:commandButton onclick="if(test) return true;else return false" action="{#bean.menthod}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working simply because the result of `test()` function is not returned to the component.

it should work as expected with

```
<h:commandButton onclick="return test()" action="{#bean.menthod}">
```

and this is exactly the same as your second case but simplified.

Comment: i want to know why result of test is not returned to the component though the test() method returns false

Comment: because you're not putting `return` before calling the function :)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Headache gone and now I can rest easy :)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day your `h:commandButton` will become a HTML Form submit button. i.e, `<input type="submit" .../>`

Usually form won't get submitted when the submit button returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.. This helped me lot. Here simple logic which i missed i.e .. in that onclick function I am returning false instead of true, which is stopping the action to be called. 
Finally i changed return value to true, and solved my issue.